# TF402594 when migrating from TFS 2018 to VSTS

Tags: tfs, migration, azure-devops

The `TFSMigrator Validate` command gives this error on one of our projects.

I can not find any instructions about how to proceed to fix this.

> [Error  @02:07:35.029] Step : ProcessValidation - Failure Type -
> Validation failed :
>
> Invalid process template: WorkItem Tracking\TypeDefinitions\CodeReviewRequest.xml:65: TF402594:
>
> File violates the schema with the following error: The element
> 'ALLOWEDVALUES' has incomplete content.
>
> List of possible elements
> expected: 'GLOBALLIST, LISTITEM'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution to this:

Take the TFS Process Template Editor from GitHub and run it in Visual Studio. 
Log into the server with this. 
Retrieve the work items.
Find the broken work item.
Find the same work item from a working project
Do a text compare of the two (I used ms word)
Carefully edit the xml of the broken work item.
Apply

Tests pass after this.